# SceneKit Particle Systems in a Swift Playground

Tags: swift, scenekit, swift-playground

Usually I instantiate SCNParticleSystems by using the file initializer like this:

`var stars =  SCNParticleSystem(named: "Stars.sncp", inDirectory: nil)`

However this project requires a Swift Playground and when I try to use that init function with systems stored in the playground's Resources folder it returns nil (even if I change the specified directory to "Resources" or "/Resources" etc. etc. ).

Are Playground resource paths handled differently to normal apps or am I making a really stupid filenaming mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're doing a mistake in filename extension. It is **.scnp** and not **.sncp**.

Either try without any extension -

```
var stars =  SCNParticleSystem(named: "Stars", inDirectory: nil)
```

or try with correct extension -

```
var stars =  SCNParticleSystem(named: "Stars.scnp", inDirectory: nil)
```

Comment: Well, that was really stupid. Thanks so much for taking the time to waste on this question though!

Answer (score 2):

**In Xcode 11 and later there's no preconfigured `.scnp` Particle System file**. Instead you can use `Particle System` object coming directly from Xcode library.

[image]

Or, as always, you can create a particle system in Xcode Playground programmatically.

---

About **Swift Playgrounds** for iPad [read here](https://medium.com/@arkit/realitykit-911-swift-playgrounds-or-how-to-create-and-debug-ar-apps-on-ipad-pro-190a6d2e03bb).

---

Here's a code:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import SceneKit

let rectangle = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1000, height: 200)
var sceneView = SCNView(frame: rectangle)

var scene = SCNScene()
sceneView.scene = scene
sceneView.backgroundColor = .black

let cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
cameraNode.position.z = 70
sceneView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

let particleSystem = SCNParticleSystem()
particleSystem.birthRate = 500
particleSystem.particleLifeSpan = 0.5
particleSystem.particleColor = .systemIndigo
particleSystem.speedFactor = 7
particleSystem.emittingDirection = SCNVector3(1,1,1)
particleSystem.emitterShape = .some(SCNSphere(radius: 15))

let particlesNode = SCNNode()
particlesNode.scale = SCNVector3(2,2,2)
particlesNode.addParticleSystem(particleSystem)
sceneView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(particlesNode)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = sceneView
```

[image]